# HTML5 audio tag

Tags: html, css, audio

in `HTML5 audio tag` is there any way I can design `HTML5 Audio tag` via `CSS`? 
I tried using

```
background-color:green
```

but there is like a transparent bg on top of it

Comment: post your http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: That is quite very helpful. Thank you. :)